# Is there a pandas way to compute a function between 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am looking for a faster way to compute some kind of function across multiple columns.

my dataframe looks like:

```
c = 12*1000
b = int(c/2)
d = int(b/2)

newdf = {'Class': ['c1']*c+['c2']*c+['c3']*c,
        'Section': ['A']*b+['B']*b+['C']*b+['D']*b+['E']*b+['F']*b,
        'Time': [1,2,3,4,5,6]*d+[3,1,3,4,5,7]*d}

test = pd.DataFrame(newdf)
test['f_x'] = test['Time']**2/5
test['f_x_2'] = test['Time']**2/5+test['f_x']
#working with 1 column
test['section_mean'] = test.groupby(['Class','Section'])['f_x'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
test['two_col_sum'] = test[['Time','f_x']].apply(lambda x: x.Time+x.f_x,axis=1)
cols = ['f_x','f_x_2']
```

and I know how to calculate for example a value for a series of columns for groups:

```
test['section_mean'] = test.groupby(['Class','Section'])['f_x'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
```

Or eventually do simple operations between more columns:

```
test['two_col_sum'] = test[['Time','f_x']].apply(lambda x: x.Time+x.f_x,axis=1)
```

However, what I'm trying to do is some kind of computation over the full column of a grouped instance:

```
%%time
slopes_df = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = test.groupby(['Class','Section'])

for name, group in grouped:
    nd=[]
    for col in cols:
        ntest = group[['Time',col]]
        x = ntest.Time
        y = ntest[col]
        f=np.polyfit(x,y, deg=1).round(2)
        data = [name[0],name[1],col,f[0],f[1]]
        nd.append(data)

    slopes_df=pd.concat([slopes_df,pd.DataFrame(nd)])

slopes_df.columns=['Class','Section','col','slope','intercept']
slopes_df_p = pd.pivot_table(data=slopes_df,index=['Class','Section'], columns=['col'], values=['slope','intercept']).reset_index()
slopes_df_p.columns = pd.Index(e[0] if e[0] in ['Class','Section'] else e[0]+'_'+e[1] for e in slopes_df_p.columns)
fdf = pd.merge(test, slopes_df_p, on=['Class','Section'])
```

I tried the solution proposed in this way:

```
%%time
for col in cols:
    df1 = (test.groupby(['Class','Section'])
              .apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(x['Time'],x[col], deg=1).round(2)[0])
              .rename('slope_'+str(col)))
    df2 = (test.groupby(['Class','Section'])
              .apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(x['Time'],x[col], deg=1).round(2)[1])
              .rename('intercept_'+str(col)))
    df1['col']=col
    df2['col']=col

    test = pd.merge(test,df1, on=['Class','Section'])
    test = pd.merge(test,df2, on=['Class','Section'])
```

but it seems slower, on my pc first loop takes 150ms and second code 300 ms

Andrea

Comment: fixed, thanks for noticing.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `x` and `y` in that loop.

Comment: You don't need `lambda` here either, just use `test.groupby(['Class','Section'])['f_x'].transform('mean')`  and `test[['Time','f_x']].sum(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop solution not working by data of groups, so I think you need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    for col in cols:
        x[f'slope_{col}'], x[f'intercept_{col}'] = np.polyfit(x['Time'],x[col], deg=1).round(2)
    return x
df1 = test.groupby(['Class','Section']).apply(f)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works wonderfully. I will try it on a bigger dataframe!
I updated the code: now it should loop over some groups and for different columns in the original dataframe.

Comment: @CassAndr - I hope working well, let me know after testing ;)

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems slower, I will update the question to clarify as here the code formatting is worse.

Comment: This is the fastest! Thanks! @jezrael
Wall time: 192 ms
Wall time: 337 ms
last solution:
Wall time: 115 ms